# connect a triac to optoisolator

Tags: opto-isolator

I want to use a current sense from the CR2550 connected to optoisolator LDA 110 and drive the gate of a triac. How do I connect these two systems with out killing either?

Update

Thanks for all the input so far.

What I am trying to do is this, when I turn on a table saw, I want to be able to sense that current and use it to drive a contactor and thus turn on a dust collector. I found this circuit  on the internet and seems to work. I get 3.5 volts from the output. Connecting it to a triac and the contactor shudders. The contactor requires 24 volts ac to run.

[image]

Comment: It helps if you add datasheets, in that way people will be able to help you better. Schematics are useful too, you can draw them clicking the icon with the diode.

Comment: Just checking, Jeremy, (1) but are you trying to switch on current in a second circuit if there is current in the first circuit? (2) Do you actually want it to switch only when current is present or / and when voltage is present? (3) What is the context of the question? Post all additional info **in your question** rather than in the comments.

Comment: What is CR2550??

Comment: A [CR2550](http://www.crmagnetics.com/remote/cr2550) is a "low-cost current indicator" made by CR Magnetics. It's basically a little current transformer driving an LED. The LED may be a bidirectional type (two back-to-back in one package) for AC use. I don't think it will work as the OP wants because it probably only lights for the part of each half-cycle when the current is high enough and therefore couldn't trigger a triac anywhere close to zero-cross.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a 24 V contactor rather than mains? Is it DC or AC? Do you have a 24 V power-supply for it?

Comment: The fact that you're only getting 3.5 V when the saw is running confirms my suspicion that it's turning off at every zero-cross as in my earlier comment.

Comment: The 24 v contactor is used to turn on the mains and run motor for dust collector. This motor draws close to 15 amps and is on a 20 amp system from power panel.

Answer (score 1):

That LDA110 doesn't appear very well suited to driving a Triac. We typically use triac opto isolators like MOC3022 for driving Triacs.

Ref: http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/moc3022/opto-isolator-triac-output/1.html

You will need some kind of amplifier and comparator setpoint circuit between your current sensor and the opto-isolator.

Comment: The current sense is being used to turn on a 24 volt contactor, turn on a motor the current sense turns on another motor.